Definition of "interval of continuity" for function defined on sets
At the beginning of Chapter 8 of Kubilius's Probabilistic Methods in the Theory of Numbers, the author defines $Q=Q(E)$ to be a completely additive nonnegative function defined for all Borel subsets $E$ of $\Bbb R^n$ (that is, some kind of measure defined on the Borel subsets of $\Bbb R^n$). The author then uses the terminology that $I$ can be an "interval of continuity" of the function $Q(E)$ (nothing more is said about what $I$ is).
What is the precise definition of "interval of continuity" in this context? Where can I find that definition?
This question was first posted on Mathematics Stack Exchange, but it didn't receive any answers for over a week. One comment made me wonder whether an interval of continuity might be a set of the form $I_1\times\cdots\times I_n$, where each $I_j$ is an interval in $\Bbb R$, such that $Q(\partial I)=0$ where $\partial I$ is the boundary of $I$; but I don't trust this hunch enough to use it without confirmation.
(Kubilius is actually talking there about Borel subsets not containing the origin, but I'm pretty sure that's irrelevant to my question.)

I'm shocked noone has answered this lol
